# No operator >> corresponds to these operands

Tags: c++

when I try to make a cin >> I got error C2679

> No operator `>>` corresponds to these operands

I try to includes header

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int Name();

void SignIn()
{
    std::cout << "enter your username : ";
    std::cin >> Name;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "allo";
    SignIn();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Name` is a function, which cannot be used in combination with operator `>>`. What was the intent?

Comment: If you want to input a name, you should change `int name()` to `std::string name`. A `int` cannot store characters, and the `()` makes it a function declaration, not a variable.

Comment: Thanks Gille-Philipe Paillé I change to string and it works

Answer (score 5):

This

```
int Name();
```

is a function declaration  with the name `Name` and the return type `int` that does not accept arguments.

If you want to declare a global variable then it is enough to write

```
int Name;
```

because the variable has the static storage duration and will be implicitly zero-initialized by the compiler.

If you want to specify explicitly the initializer then you can write

```
int Name = 0;
```

or

```
int Name = {};
```

or

```
int Name{};
```

But it seems you mean an object of the type std::string. Then you can write

```
std::string Name;
```